# HTML/CSS image on top of an image with a finxed nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, computer-science

I have a fixed navigation bar and an image on my webpage. I want to add another image on top of this image, but when I use "position: relative" and position:absolute", and I scroll, the 2 images go over my navigation bar.

Can anyone help?

I can post code if needed.

```css
(menueBar.css)
#menu-bar {
   font-family: Arial; 
   font-size: 20px; 
 }

#name {
 color: #ccc;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

#nav{ background-color: #222;
      position: fixed; 
      width: 100%; 
      height: 133px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0; 
    }

#nav-wrapper{ width: 600px;
           margin: 0px 0 0 50px; 
           text-align:left; 
         }

#nav ul{ list-style-type: none; 
   padding: 0 0 0 0; 
  
  }

#nav ul li{ display: inline-block; }

#nav ul li:hover{ background-color: #333; }

#nav ul li a{ color: #CCC; 
      display: block;
        padding: 15px ; 
     text-decoration: none; 
    }



------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(main.css)


body {
 font-family:arial;
} 

h1,h2{
 margin-top: 0px;
 color:blue;
 
}

p {
 background: #666;
 color: white;
 padding : 10px;
}

#header-footer {
 margin:  66px 0 0 0;
 
}
```

```html
----------------------------------------------
(index.html)

<!doctype html>
<html>

 <!--global~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
 <head>
  <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="styles/menuBar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>My WebPage</title>
 </head>

 <div id="menu-bar">
 <body>
  <div id="nav">
       <div id="nav-wrapper">
          <div id="name" >
        <p1 style="font-size:40px">Manish Saraf</p1>
       </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html"><u>Home</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="page3.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="page4.html">Contact me</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </div>

 <!--global~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ --> 

 <!--Header-footer~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
 <div id ="header-footer" >
  <img src="images/header-footer.jpg" id="header-footer" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <img src="images/me.jpg" id="me" style="width:100px; height:100px; ">
 </div>
 <!--header-footer~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->


  <h1>My Website</h1>
  <h2>This is my homepage</h2>
  <p>And all my homepage Content</p>

</html>
--------------------------------------------------

(page2.html)(resume)
<!doctype html>
<html>

 <!--global~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

 <head>
  <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="styles/menuBar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Resume</title>
 </head>

 <div id="menu-bar">
 <body>
  <div id="nav">
      <div id="nav-wrapper">
          <div id="name" >
        <p1 style="font-size:40px">Manish Saraf</p1>
       </div>
           <ul>
                 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="page2.html"><u>Resume</u></a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Projects</a></li>
                 <li><a href="page4.html">Contact me</a></li>
           </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </div>
 <!--global~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

  <h1>Page 2</h1>
  <h2>This is my page 2</h2>
  <p>And all my page 2 Content</p>

 </body>

</html>
---------------------------------------------------------------
(page3.html)(projects)
<!doctype html>
<html>

 <!--global~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

 <head>
  <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="styles/menuBar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Projects</title>
 </head>

 <div id="menu-bar">
 <body>
  <div id="nav">
      <div id="nav-wrapper">
          <div id="name" >
        <p1 style="font-size:40px">Manish Saraf</p1>
       </div>
           <ul>
                 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="page2.html">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html"><u>Projects</u></a></li>
                 <li><a href="page4.html">Contact me</a></li>
           </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </div>
 <!--global~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->





  <h1>Page 3</h1>
  <h2>This is my page 3</h2>
  <p>And all my page 3 Content</p>

 </body>

</html>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
(page4.html)(contact me)
<!doctype html>
<html>

 <!--global~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

 <head>
  <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="styles/menuBar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Contact Me</title>
 </head>

 <div id="menu-bar">
 <body>
  <div id="nav">
      <div id="nav-wrapper">
          <div id="name" >
        <p1 style="font-size:40px">Manish Saraf</p1>
       </div>
           <ul>
                 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="page2.html">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Projects</a></li>
                 <li><a href="page4.html"><u>Contact me</u></a></li>
           </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </div>
 <!--global~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

  <h1>Page 4</h1>
  <h2>This is my page 4</h2>
  <p>And all my page 4 Content</p>

 </body>

</html>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You just need to add `#menu-bar { z-index:10;}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but this looks like it could be just a `z-index` issue.

Try putting in the CSS `z-index:0` on the element that should be below, and `z-index:1`on the element that should be on top.

[See if this helps](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)